# Highcharts: Wind Rose chart with JSON data

Tags: highcharts, label

I am create a new wind rose highcharts graph, and have 37 columns
each column has it's own value (using JSON data)

But when I create the windorse chart the labels are not displayed as should
'S0', 'S32'....

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JaTjk/2/

Comment: How do you want the labels to look ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `pointStart` and `pointInterval`, which is unnecessary.

See fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/JaTjk/5/