# how to use json for Wind rose polar highchart insted of table data

Tags: json, highcharts

```
 data: {
        table: 'freq',
        startRow: 1,
        endRow: 17,
        endColumn: 7
    },
```

please help, how to use json for Wind rose polar highchart instead of table data. 
https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/26njzy7k/1/

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189590/highcharts-polar-chart-wind-rose-data-from-json and http://jsfiddle.net/JaTjk/5/

Answer (score 2):

I'm late here but posting up the answer for other people who may visit the question. I struggled to get it right too. The answers in linked questions don't quite get it because they use raw wind speeds not wind frequencies when dealing with polar wind roses without the table data from the example in highcharts demo.

The polar version is similar to stacked columns chart only think of it as the x-axis wrapped around a circle. The x-axis shows the wind directions, the categories option defines these. The y-axis shows the wind speed buckets. The series data is structured as

```
         //data series
         {
            //series 1
            name: '10-20 kmph',
            //basically the frequencies for that wind speed across all the directions
            //1.5% comes from N, 4.5% from NNE, 3.0% from NE, etc 
            data: [1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 0 ... ]
         },
         {
            //series 2
            name: '20-30 kmph',
            data: [1.2, 3.6, 0, .... ]
         }
         //so on
```

The code I used is here, it crunches up the frequency data obtained via json:

```
          //chart no.1 - wind rose
          $scope.windRoseConfig = {
              options: {
                  chart: { polar: true, type: 'column' },
                  yAxis: {
                     title: { text: 'Frequency' }, 
                     reversedStacks: false
                  },
                  plotOptions: {
                     series: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        shadow: false,
                        groupPadding: 0,
                        pointPlacement: 'on'
                     }
                  }
              },

              title: { text: 'Wind Rose' },

              series: seriesData,

              xAxis: {
                  tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                  categories: [ "N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW" ]
              }
          }

       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the demo using JSON here: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/IamMHussain/fba8ts5f/1/)

```
series: [
    {
      name: '10-20 kmph',
      data: [1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5]
    },
    {
      name: '20-30 kmph',
      data: [1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5]
    }
],
xAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    categories: ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"]
},
```